# PHP search string containing special characters and foreign letters

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace

I have a very simpel search function which search for a product name in a mysql database.

When i'm searching for any product using A-Z the functions is working fine.

However, i have a product with the name "product & nämë".

When searching for this product i get 0 results - even though im searching for the exact name of the product.

The problem i have, i believe, is because of the characters 'ö ä ë &'.

What is the best practice allowing me to search for products with these characters.

My code is as following:
The search query:

```
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^ \w]+/", "", $_GET["find"]);
$query_products_category_id = 'WHERE product_name LIKE "%'. $search_string .'%"';
```

- I also tried using the regular expression for using letters A-Z allowing the '&' character but then i had a problem with the special letters.

If you could just point me to a function or another approach it would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) ?

Comment: Mysqli escape still returns the value: product  nm

Comment: And "$search_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["find"]);" simply doesn't find any products even if the names are exact the same :S

Comment: This might help
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050723/how-can-i-preg-replace-special-character-like-pr%C3%AAt-%C3%A0-porter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050723/how-can-i-preg-replace-special-character-like-pr%C3%AAt-%C3%A0-porter)